# Getting Failedto load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder even though I seem to have bindings with my Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, log4j, logback

So I searched through and found this problem all over Stack Overflow, and the solution is usually IDE related (You need an external Version of Maven!), wrong version of the loggers (Tried the newest ones), and lastly the lack of choosing a binder.

So I have a Maven project with the following dependencies for my logging needs:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion> 
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Even though I have a bound logger in there (Two in fact, slf4j and Logback), whenever I compile on my computer or push it to compile on my Jenkins box I get the:

> Failedto load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

for every one of my modules. Any possible solutions to try would be appreciated.

Comment: Not related to your question but you don't need to exclude the slf4j-log4j12 dependency here since it is not a dependency of slf4j-api. Also, jcl-over-slf4j should have runtime scope since it is not used for compilation.

Comment: I suspect you use the wrong dependency. Can you try replacing jcl-over-slf4j with slf4j-jcl? Also, why did you specify two logging framework (i.e. JCL and Logback)?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache : This is legacy code causing problems that they do not feel like fixing, nor do I think he truly understood what he was doing. I tried just using ONE framework (Logback) still got the error. Gonna try and get rid of the exclusion and JCL (So just use Logback) and get back to you.

Comment: Fixed! So here was my problem. Not every module had the api/bound logger. And we had several instances of several different loggers. After cleaning up per your suggestions and removing dead weight, logs have come back to the promised land!